# "You came even though you're sick?" Do these mixed tenses make this grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar

Mixed tenses make this sentence wrong?

Comment: The sentence is correct, assuming the person was still sick when the question was asked.

Comment: *You **came**, even though you **will be** refused entry.*